# How to resolve CGDirectDisplayID changing issues on newer multi-GPU Apple laptops in Core Foundation/IO Kit?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, core-foundation, iokit, multi-gpu

In Mac OS X, every display gets a unique `CGDirectDisplayID` number assigned to it.  You can use `CGGetActiveDisplayList(`) or `[NSScreen screens]` to access them, among others.  Per [Apple's docs](http://CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback):

> A display ID can persist across
>   processes and system reboot, and
>   typically remains constant as long as
>   certain display parameters do not
>   change.

On newer mid-2010 MacBook Pro's, Apple started using auto-switching Intel/nVidia graphics.  Laptops have two GPU's, a low-powered Intel, and a high-powered nVidia.  Previous dual-GPU laptops (2009 models) didn't have auto-GPU switching, and required the user to make a settings change, logoff, and then logon again to make a GPU switch occur.  Even older systems only had one GPU.

There's an issue with the mid-2010 models where CGDirectDisplayID's don't remain the same when a display switches from one GPU to the next.  For example:

1. Laptop powers on.
2. Built-In **LCD
   Screen** is driven by Intel chipset. 
   Display ID:  **30002**
3. **External
   Display** is plugged in.
4. Built-In
   **LCD Screen** switches to nVidia
   chipset.  It's display ID changes: 
   **30004**
5. **External Display** is driven
   by nVidia chipset.
6. ...at this point,
   the Intel chipset is dormant...
7. User unplugs **External Display**.
8. Built-In **LCD Screen** switches back to
   Intel chipset.  It's display ID
   changes back to original: **30002**

**My question is, how can I match an old display ID to a new display ID when they alter due to a GPU change?**

---

**Thought about:**

I've noticed that the display ID only changes by 2, but I don't have enough test Mac's available to determine if this is common to all new MacBook Pro's, or just mine.  Kind of a kludge if "just check for display ID's which are +/-2 from one another" works, anyway.

---

**Tried:**

`CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback()`, which notifies before-and-after when displays are going to change, has no matching logic.  Putting something like this inside a method registered with it doesn't work:

```
// Run before display settings change:
CGDirectDisplayID directDisplayID = ...;
io_service_t    servicePort = CGDisplayIOServicePort(directDisplayID);
CFDictionaryRef oldInfoDict = IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary(servicePort, kIODisplayMatchingInfo);

// ...display settings change...

// Run after display settings change:
CGDirectDisplayID directDisplayID = ...;
io_service_t    servicePort = CGDisplayIOServicePort(directDisplayID);
CFDictionaryRef newInfoDict = IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary(servicePort, kIODisplayMatchingInfo);
BOOL match = IODisplayMatchDictionaries(oldInfoDict, newInfoDict, 0);

if (match)
    NSLog(@"Displays are a match");
else
    NSLog(@"Displays are not a match");
```

What's happening above is:

1. I'm caching **oldInfoDict** before display settings change.
2. Waiting for display settings to change
3. Then comparing **oldInfoDict** to **newInfoDict** by using `IODisplayMatchDictionaries()`
4. `IODisplayMatchDictionaries()` returns a BOOL, either YES they're the same, or NO they're different.

Unfortunately, `IODisplayMatchDictionaries()` doesn't return YES if the same display changed GPU's.  Here's an example of the dictionary's it's comparing (look at the `IODisplayLocation` key):

```
// oldInfoDict  (Display ID: 30002)
oldInfoDict: {
    DisplayProductID = 40144;
    DisplayVendorID = 1552;
    IODisplayLocation = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2/AppleIntelFramebuffer/display0/AppleBacklightDisplay";
}

// newInfoDict  (Display ID: 30004)
newInfoDict: {
    DisplayProductID = 40144;
    DisplayVendorID = 1552;
    IODisplayLocation = "IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/P0P2@1/IOPCI2PCIBridge/GFX0@0/NVDA,Display-A@0/NVDA/display0/AppleBacklightDisplay";
}
```

As you can see, the `IODisplayLocation` key changes when GPU's are switched, hence `IODisplayMatchDictionaries()` doesn't work.

I can, theoretically, compared just the `DisplayProductID` and `DisplayVendorID` keys, but I'm writing end-user software, and am worried of a situation where users have two or more identical monitors plugged in (meaning they'll both have the same DisplayProductID/DisplayVendorID).  In other words, it's a less-than-perfect solution open to potential glitches.

---

Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: When a GPU change happens, the flags sent to the call back include an undocumented one: `#define kCGDisplayMysteryGPUChangedFlag (1 << 13) // Undocumented post-reconfiguration callback flag for i5/i7 systems`

Answer (score 8):

Use CFUUIDRef which can be obtained using:

`CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID(CGDirectDisplayID displayID)`
and you can get the display ID back using:

`CGDisplayGetDisplayIDFromUUID(CFUUIDRef uuid)`

This is what I'm using to uniquely identify displays even when their CGDirectDisplayID changes, for example was plugged into a different port. These functions aren't properly documented by Apple unfortunately, but my testing on multiple Macs with multiple displays shown that the CFUUIDRef obtained is unique and consistent -even after a reboot-, regardless of whether CGDirectDisplayID changed for whatever reason.

To check if a display is new/unique, take its CGDirectDisplayID and convert it to CFUUIDRef, and then compare the UUID, it is a many-to-one relationship, many CGDirectDisplayIDs will map to a single CFUUIDRef.

These API calls are available in ApplicationServices in 10.7 - 10.12, and ColorSync since 10.13.

Answer (score 5):

I have found no conceputally better way than what you list as "Tried". But I found a solution for the ambiguity issue of comparing only vendor id and product id.

`oldInfoDict` and `newInfoDict` in your code contain an additional entry for key `kIODisplayEDIDKey` (defined in [IOGraphicsTypes.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOGraphics/IOGraphics-233/IOGraphicsFamily/IOKit/graphics/IOGraphicsTypes.h)) which contains the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) of each connected display. My observations show that this data as a whole stays persistent between GPU switches. For example:

```
    CGDirectDisplayID displayId = [[[screen deviceDescription] valueForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedIntValue];
    io_service_t displayPort = CGDisplayIOServicePort(displayId);

    if (displayPort == MACH_PORT_NULL)
        return nil;  // No physical device to get a name from.

    CFDictionaryRef infoDict = IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary(displayPort, kIODisplayOnlyPreferredName);

    NSData *displayEdid = (NSData *)CFDictionaryGetValue(infoDict, CFSTR(kIODisplayEDIDKey));
    NSLog(@"EDID: %@", displayEdid);

    CFRelease(infoDict);
```

Looking at the data description of [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) in Wikipedia, this blob already contains manufacturer, product id and serial. So it's enough to compare displays by using the EDID data (or for example a hash of it if you only want to compare a shorter number).

Comment: Do you know if the EDID data blob is unique for *every* display? That is, will two Thunderbolt Displays have different EDID blobs? Note that the "serial number" is always zero, so some other aspect of the EDID must be different. Basically, I'm looking for a reliable way to identify the same physical display in all conditions.

Comment: Do you mean two identical display models connected on Thunderbolt? If it's not the same model or even different vendors, then I am pretty sure the EDID will be different. If it's the same make and model, and the serial is not populated, then it might be hard to tell them apart. The serial being zero might be a vendor specific issue, have you tried different displays?

Comment: I haven’t tried any other vendors, but apple’s displays definitely have the serial number set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm no pro, I believe the answer is to allow Apple to [*notify*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags) you when the user changes displays.  The info inf the callback contains flags for adding and removing `CGDirectDisplayID`s.

The user shouldn't be adding or removing graphics cards during operation, so I would play with making list at startup, and whenever you get the "remove" flag set the next "add" operation to replace that ID in the list.

I'd try just printing the information you get back each time `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback` calls your function.  See if you get one with a DeviceUID with a 'remove' flag, and then a subsequent call another with an 'add' flag.  Checking those id's against `CGGetActiveDisplayList` would also aid in understanding what's going on.

That's my best bet, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Sadly, the notification's don't have anything saying "DisplayID ABC has now become DisplayID XYZ".

What I've found out since posting this question is display ID's can change dynamically at runtime at any time.  For example, if you launch Adobe Photoshop CS4, mid-2010 MacBook Pro's switch from Intel integrated graphics to nVidia discrete graphics.  This makes sense since Photoshop CS4+ is GPU intensive.  However, the displayID for your monitor changes during GPU-switches.  Once you exist Photoshop, it falls back to the Intel GPU, and the displayID changes again.  Fun!  :)

Comment: True, but you should still get one callback for the remove ID and one for the add ID, no?

Comment: @DaveGallagher did you try using CFUUIDRef? CFUUIDRef from my anecdotal experience was always consistent, even when CGDirectDisplayID changes, even across reboots.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using:

```
-(NSString *)uuidForDisplayID:(CGDirectDisplayID)displayID
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID (displayID);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString (kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidRef);
    CFRelease (uuidRef);
    
    return ([(NSString *)string autorelease]);
}
```

However during a display removal event in the call back, even during the initial `kCGDisplayBeginConfigurationFlag`, the call to `CGDisplayCreateUUIDFromDisplayID` fails with an 'invalid displayID' error, thus I see no way to go from a ambiguous CGDirectDisplayID back to a stable UUID when a display is being removed.

Interestingly, one can still get the array of NSScreens and search for one matching the CGDirectDisplayID:

`[[[screen deviceDescription] objectForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedLongValue]`

In Xcode the `NSScreen` has a property called `_UUIDString` which contains the same UUID but I see no way to get this UUID out of the NSScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this post, and did some digging based on things I've observed. Maybe there is useful information in /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist. It's in plist format, so this command should be used to decode it to the terminal:

```
plutil -p /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist
```

If you find something useful, please respond.

Comment: I think this file is updated when you attach a screen to the system, but also when you do certain operations in the "Displays" System Preferences app, so it has entries back over some time and includes my built-in retina display.